# Use VBA FIND() function (or analogy) in an unopened spreasheet

Tags: vba, excel

**What I am trying to do:**

Create a data query userform using VBA that will allow a user to query daily data. This would usually be a very simple project, but is only necessary because a sufficient database for this data has not been built. Currently, a separate spreadsheet is saved every day onto a shared drive. Built into the title of each spreadsheet is the date. (Ex: "H:SharedDrive/DataSheets/2May2012.xls"). In each spreadsheet is a variety of data recorded each day; each piece of data has a category that is constant from day-to-day (these category names are locked for editing).

**My Original Approach**

I created a simple userform that allows a user to enter the date range of the desired query and the *spreadsheet address* of the desired data. After several trials, I found that actually opening every spreadsheet and copy and pasting data into a new sheet was quite lengthy, especially if the user is querying over a time-span of years. I then began to use "ExecuteExcel4Macro()" to query the data from each spreadsheet without actually opening each individually. This worked great and perfectly accomplished what I needed.

**The Problem**

It turns out that those who enter the data into these spreadsheets on a day-to-day basis have not retained a uniform format for data entry over time. Often, a new row or column is added into the spreadsheet before saving the filled-out template to the shared drive. Therefore, just because the address of a particular piece of data has been "H69" for the past two months does not mean that the format was not changed two months ago and that same piece of data was previously housed in cell "H72". This presents an obvious problem for my program.

**What I have Tried**

I have tried to use the actual category names to query a piece of data. These category names never change over time. For example, the user records pressure and temperature in cells labeled "pressure" and "temperature" in the column to the left of the data-entry cells. The address of the recorded data is not constant over time, but the words "pressure" and "temperature" cannot be changed. The easiest way I know to retrieve the address of a piece of data within a spreadsheet is the Find() function. However, as far as I have been able to find, this function only works on a sheet in an open workbook. Which brings me back to my original problem, which is longer query times associated with opening individual spreadsheets (too long to be an effective tool).

Is there an analogy to the Find() function that works for unopened workbooks?

Comment: Those workbooks will need to be open to be searched. Or, those workbooks could, on closing, save a separate .CSV file which contains your data that Excel could open and search. Or, you could protect the worksheets in the source files so that no one can insert rows.

Comment: Obviously, going forward, some basic improvements in data-recording can be made. The question was more addressing data that has been recorded in the past. This data-reporting system has been in place since 2002, so at this point, it is very hard to query all of that data. Thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Can you use ExecuteExcel4Macro to bring in a slightly larger range than what was requested and use Find on that to narrow down the particular cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am unable to use FIND(), I use a loop to check values.
You can use RC notation and an x and y variable to loop through the data in the sheet. Then check for your key words. Once the key word is found, calculate an offset for the data.

Note: It takes about 1 second to check 500 cells so I would try to keep the range you loop through small.

```
sub test()
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim myfile As String
Dim myvalue As Variant


For x = 1 To 10
For y = 1 To 50
    myfile = "'C:\Users\jmgri798\Documents\GRMRS\Temp\[Test Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!r" & x & "c" & y
    myvalue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(myfile)
    If myvalue = "DEF" Then
        myfile = "'C:\Users\jmgri798\Documents\GRMRS\Temp\[Test Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!r" & x & "c" & y + 1
        myvalue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(myfile)
        Sheet1.Range("b2") = myvalue
    End If
Next y
Next x
end sub
```